# Is there a way to tell when the page was last redrawn?

Tags: javascript, html

Like some global timestamp or such?

I'm devising a hacky way to reduce getBoundingClientRect calls by caching the result and hoping to tie it to this timestamp which would presumably change whenever anything in the document changes.

Comment: Not really, but for gBCR update, lurking at `resize` and `scroll` events is already a good thing (remember to debounce the handlers), and if you've got control on DOM manipulation, update a node insertion/removal.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is what you are looking for but you may go with jquery "document ready" to detect that your page have been fully refreshed and use a JS interval timer to know the "age" of our page (here is in seconds but you can go for millis)

```js
$(document ).ready(function()
{
 var sec=0;
  
 var timer = window.setInterval(timer, 1000);
  
  function timer()
  {
  $("#window_time").html(sec);
    sec++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Time since refresh : <span id="window_time">0</span> second
```